# find the qth lower tail quantile

Tags: returns, distribution, excel

I have daily currency returns. For each month, I have to find the return associated to the 5% lower tail quantile for each currency (the lowest return or the second lowest return).

Could you please tell me how to do it using Excel?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use =PERCENTILE(range, 0.05)

where range refers to the returns in question

Answer (score 0):

Just arrange your data in ascending or descending order using filter tab in Excel.

> Data $<-$ Filter $<-$ Sort Smallest to Largest

[image]

If there are 20 days in each month, then select second lowest return for each month.

Otherwise, You may use parametric approach to estimate 5% lower quantile for each and every month.

Answer (score 0):

Use this R package: Performance Analytics
Link: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/PerformanceAnalytics/index.html